# Convert TIF/TIFF to JPG : Bad endianness tag

Tags: java, jpeg, tiff, endianness, jai

I am trying to convert TIF / TIFF images to JPG which works fine but for few TIF images I am getting an IllegalArgumentException: Bad endianness tag (not 0x4949 or 0x4d4d).

Exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Bad endianness tag (not 0x4949 or 0x4d4d).
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.CodecUtils.toIOException(CodecUtils.java:76)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFImageDecoder.getNumPages(TIFFImageDecoder.java:98)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(TIFFImageDecoder.java:103)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoderImpl.decodeAsRenderedImage(ImageDecoderImpl.java:140)
    at com.pkg.jae.utils.GenericImageUtils.convertTiffToJpg(GenericImageUtils.java:35)
    at com.pkg.jae.utils.GenericImageUtils.main(GenericImageUtils.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad endianness tag (not 0x4949 or 0x4d4d).
    at com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDirectory.getNumDirectories(TIFFDirectory.java:595)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFImageDecoder.getNumPages(TIFFImageDecoder.java:96)
    ... 4 more
```

Code Function :

```
public static void convertTiffToJpg(String strTiffUrl,String strJpgFileDestinationUrl) throws Exception {
        try {
            FileSeekableStream obj_FileSeekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(new File(strTiffUrl));
            ImageDecoder obj_ImageDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(EXT_TIFFX, obj_FileSeekableStream, null);
            RenderedImage obj_RenderedImage = obj_ImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage();
            JAI.create("filestore", obj_RenderedImage,strJpgFileDestinationUrl, EXT_JEPGX);
            obj_RenderedImage = null;
            obj_ImageDecoder = null;
            obj_FileSeekableStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

If anyone knows the issue and can help in this.

Comment: Inspect that TIFF file with a hex editor. What are the first 4 bytes?

Comment: I inspected image in hex editor. I see something like, ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46...

Comment: That means you're passing a JPEG file to it when it's expecting a TIFF file.

Comment: Got the point ! It means it is a jpeg file with tiff extension.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment by [bitbank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104109/bitbank), this means you're passing a JPEG file to it when it expects to get a TIFF file.

Answer (score -1):

Startlingly, this JAI

```
RenderedOp renderer = JAI.create("fileload", filename);
BufferedImage bi = renderer.getAsBufferedImage();
```

does not have the same failure and just works regardless of image "kind." Don't use this particular method (passing in the filename) though, see [Is JAI closing file handles too early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444752/is-jai-closing-file-handles-too-early)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and it turned out to be a front-end problem. Yes, I was trying to upload the wrong file type, but I was expecting correct handling and a gracious popup message alert. Instead I was getting the error you described.

In my case, I was using extjs and I had a failure function like this:

```
failure: function (a) {
...some message alert...
}
```

instead of:

```
failure: function (f, a) {
...some message alert...
}
```

and this was throwing that exception, instead of displaying my message alert.